# Is it acceptable to use the masked GitHub email address when generating the SSH key for GitHub?

Tags: email, git, github

GitHub provides the masked address I can use in form of `4632864+username@users.noreply.github.com`.

According to the website below I should start generating the key with `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "your_email@example.com"`

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

My question is, do I need to use my primary email address that is set on GitHub or I can just use the masked address there, like so:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -C "4632864+username@users.noreply.github.com"
```

I have the `4632864+username@users.noreply.github.com` added to my GPG uuids. It is shown when I use `gpg --list-keys`.

Or should I use the master address that I set when I first generated the GPG key with `gpg --full-generate-key` ? I prefer to keep my main email address private from GitHub. If I add the SSH key to GitHub, will my primary email be revealed?

Comment: You can use whatever email you want. It won't be used past the generation process.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking in using the master email that I used when I created the GPG key, however when I export it to be uploaded to GitHub `cat ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub` it shows `ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1.... masteremail@mydomain.com` This is the stuff I paste into the GitHub settings website SSH section. Will this procedure discloses the address to GitHub?

Comment: GitHub is already aware of your email.  Are you asking if your email identity will be linked to the key, viewable by other users?

Comment: It is not aware because I do not use the master email on Github. The primary email that is set on GitHub is a different address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key comment is just that: A comment. It is not part of the authentication process and also not used by GitHub in any way. You could just put “blah” in there and it would be totally fine. The comment is also not visible in the UI later, so it’s not clear whether GitHub stores it at all.

The comment is saved in the private key file (if the format allows for that) and also visible as plain text in the public key file:

```
ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIAZ5DBGiG/mkZSqJjuhAvFloZDbrZZtEYPQ3ka+HAaZw daniel@db-d-18
```

It defaults to “username@hostname”. Good comments help organize an `authorized_keys` file that contains many keys. That’s not required for GitHub though because you must manually name the keys you add. Other Git hosting providers may handle this part differently.

Comment: Thank you. If I use the masked `4632864+username@users.noreply.github.com` address that GitHub provides for all pushes, then the underlying email address doesn't matter that much anymore. Right? I mean, let's say my primary GitHub email is set to a Gmail address but in a few months I change it to a Yahoo address. This change shouldn't affect the previous commits right ? because they were all pushed with `4632864+username@users.noreply.github.com` which always stays the same regardless if the primary email is Gmail or Yahoo. `git log` shows `4632864+username@users.noreply...` for all commits.

Comment: Git commits are immutable. Whatever address you set in GitHub also does not affect any commits pushed by you at all, neither past nor future.